# Flash z-index in iframe

Tags: html, css

so this is a problem:
when I'm using flash on website, and creating some dialog box which should be over all other elements I use just proper z-index for dialog box (in IE6 it's needed to set transparent wmode for flash). But flash programmer don't want to give me flash file and suggested to use iframe linking to his website.

- on my website there is iframe
- in iframe there is a flash object
- when showing dialog box flash is over dialogbox (not depending of z-index and even wmode that I set by firebug)

I can't get touch with flash developer (anyway he sad that flash object will still remain on his website) so maybe you have any solution?
and weird thing:
- on some pc's it's working properly, one some not. what can be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

Because Flash is being rendered by a plugin, I don't think changes made to the `wmode` property in Firebug will have immediate effect. You'll need to add the `wmode="transparent"` in the source and reload the page.

Comment: I'll check it soon (just need to contact with flash developer)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, wmode=transparent worked for me. (using flash inside iframe, IE bug)